# How to control the log level in soapUI testrunner?

Tags: soapui

I am using the testrunner.bat to run soapUI tests. It's all good except that the its the log level is DEBUG and my test runs are too verbose. Please can someone guide me how to set the log level?

Comment: This is ranking high on the search tubes. Where and how is one supposed to ask questions on this matter? I don't see a better place. Hint?

Comment: Amazing! The solution is not too intuitive. You must edit "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\soapui-log4j.xml" file AND (most important) when you execute a testrunner.bat from a command line you have to set a current directory in your bat file to soapui bin folder (cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin").
__________ 
Reason: if the current execution folder is not the soapui bin folder, the test runs but it disregards the "soapui-log4j.xml" settings, including your cumsomisations.

Comment: Not sure about the testrunner but I added the soapui.bat file to include set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j.configuration="%SOAPUI_HOME%soapui-log4j.xml" and in the soapui-log4j.xml to set all Threshold levels in appenders and Level in loggers as per your need and it seemed to work fine.